# Referencing components in separate .JSX file

Tags: .net, reactjs

I'm am using some ReactJS components for my views in a .Net MVC application.

Currently I have a single file containing all my components at: `/scripts/react-app/MyApp.jsx`

I'd like to split this into multiple files but when I move components into another file I get a run-time exception:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: SomeComponent is not defined
```

How can I tell `MyApp.jsx` to reference another `.jsx` file?

**EDIT:**

I've tried bundling as suggested but I'm still getting the same error. Here's what I've done:

Added the below to `BundleConfig.cs`:

```
 bundles.Add(new JsxBundle("~/bundles/main").Include(
         "~/React/FileOne.jsx",
         "~/React/FileTwo.jsx",
         "~/React/FileThree.jsx"));
```

And in my `_Layout.cshtml` I've added: `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/main")`

I'm trying to use a component defined in `FileThree.jsx` in `FileOne.jsx` but still getting the `component is not defined` error.

**SECOND EDIT:**

I changed to use Html helper in view and it started working for me:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Testing";
}

<div id="someContent">
    @Html.React("FileOneComponent", new
        {
            prop1 = "a",
            prop2 = "b",
        })
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@0.13.3/dist/react.js"></script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/main")
@Html.ReactInitJavaScript()
```

Comment: are you using reactjs.net? Or, just using ReactJs? You should be using `require` and bundling.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I'm using ReactJS.Net. Could you give me an example of using `require`?

Comment: Have you tried just bundling multiple files per their docs?

Comment: I've tried bundling but it doesn't seem to work. I'm finding it difficult to find a concrete example of referencing a component in another file - it seems like it should be trivial?

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? Does the error change? The bundled file should include all files and you'll need to reference the bundled file. I don't disagree that the docs are poor with concrete examples, but the bundling docs are decent.

Comment: @WiredPrairie The error is the same. I've edited my answer to detail what I did. Am I doing something incorrectly here?

Comment: If you look at the result of `bundles/main`, does it include both components as you'd expect?

Comment: Yes, it looks to contain everything.

Comment: add a `debugger; ` right before `SomeComponent` is first used. It doesn't make sense from what you've provided here.... :/

Comment: @WiredPrairie I finally got it working. The bundling was the answer I was looking for - just took me a while to get view right. If you post as answer I will accept. Thanks.

Comment: Hi  RagtimeWilly, I`m getting same problem. Could you please share example files with proper code ? 
 "~/React/FileOne.jsx",
         "~/React/FileTwo.jsx"

Answer (score 1):

To require a component first export it (in its own file), for example:

```
export default MyComponent;
```

In the file you want to use it you require it as follows:

```
import MyComponent from './mycomponent';
```

Be sure to specify the path correctly, in my example it assumes the same folder.

If you're having any bundling problems I'd heartily recommend [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)

This sets you up with a working dev environment, including tests.

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking advantage of ReactJS.NET's server-side rendering- have you checked that the file containing **SomeComponent** is included in the ReactConfig.cs file (Under App_Start)?

If the root component being rendered by @Html.React uses SomeComponent, its code file must also be included in that server-side bundle.

**Edit**
I missed the Second Edit in the question which stated that you had solved your problem. I supposed the above may be useful for anyone using server-side rendering with separate files in the future.